# How to combine these two SQL queries into one?

Tags: sql

Show the cities where there are more requests than offers.

I have made these two queries to display how many requests are from the consumers in each city, and then one for suppliers with offers in each city. Yes this is part of a lab, and I am given each output, but I've been stuck on this one for 2 hours now and I've tried everything I can think of, it's the last problem too.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.Con_ID) 'Requests', city
FROM tb_requests r, Tb_Consumer c, Tb_Product p
WHERE r.Con_ID = c.Con_ID
  AND r.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
  ANd p.Name = 'computer'
  group by city

SELECT COUNT(s.supp_id) 'Offers', city
FROM Tb_offers o, Tb_supplier s, Tb_Product p
WHERE o.supp_ID = s.supp_ID
  AND o.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
  ANd p.Name = 'computer'
  GROUP By city
```

The output is like this:

```
Number      city
----------- ------------------------------
2           New York
4           Wausau

(2 row(s) affected)

Number      city
----------- ------------------------------
2           Chicago
1           London
4           Madison
2           Stevens Point
3           Wausau

(5 row(s) affected)
```

The correct output should be this (which is them together):

```
City                           Computer Offers Computer Requests
------------------------------ --------------- -----------------
Wausau                         3               4

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You query is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Those join are from 97! Please use proper Join syntax to join table it will be easier for you to read and maintain. We can look picky but you know it's for a greater good.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to inner join on `city`

Comment: When you created your post using the SQL tag, you were shown a large box that **strongly recommended** you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because features and syntax differ between them. Why did you ignore that advice? All you've done is wasted people's time either posting invalid answers because they've picked the wrong one, or yours by having to wait until we ask you to clarify. If you want help here, be **specific** about what you're asking, and pay attention to suggestions you get when posting.

Comment: Do you even attempt to try to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask SQL question, please add your DBMS (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc.)

It's not just about bothering you, but with SQL the syntax may strongly change depending of the DB.

---

After saying this, I'll go with ANSI SQL (should work on every decent DB) :

```
SELECT t1.city, Offers, Requests
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(c.Con_ID) Requests, city
    FROM tb_requests r, Tb_Consumer c, Tb_Product p
    WHERE r.Con_ID = c.Con_ID
    AND r.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
    ANd p.Name = 'computer'
    group by city
    ) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(s.supp_id) Offers, city
    FROM Tb_offers o, Tb_supplier s, Tb_Product p
    WHERE o.supp_ID = s.supp_ID
    AND o.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
    ANd p.Name = 'computer'
    GROUP By city
    ) t2
    ON t1.city = t2.city
WHERE Requests > Offers
```

And if you want something a bit more clean, this should do exactly the same :

```
SELECT city, COUNT(s.supp_id) Offers, COUNT(c.Con_ID) Requests
FROM Tb_Product p
    LEFT JOIN Tb_offers o ON p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID
        LEFT JOIN Tb_supplier s ON o.supp_ID = s.supp_ID
    LEFT JOIN tb_requests r ON p.Prod_ID = r.Prod_ID
        LEFT JOIN Tb_Consumer c ON r.Con_ID = c.Con_ID
WHERE p.Name = 'computer'
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(c.Con_ID) > COUNT(s.supp_id)
```

Comment: If it's clear that more information is needed before an accurate answer can be made, then it's counter-productive to go ahead and post an answer. It removes all incentive from the poster to improve or clarify if you've guessed correctly. You've also not explained why this would be the answer or made any effort to share knowledge; you've just dumped SQL. The only text you've provided is exactly the comment you should have left to the question instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for not including everything, I don't usually ask for help that often!